# Is it possible to not use ellipsis in ngx-pagination?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic3, ngx-pagination

I'm using [ngx-pagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination) package and trying to implement this:

[image]

But this is what I have until now:

[image]

My HTML:

```
<pagination-controls responsive="true" directionLinks="false"></pagination-controls>
```

My CSS:

```
.ngx-pagination {
    .current {
        background: orange;
    }
}
```

- Do you know if would it be possible to put more space between the different items? Thus incrementing the width of the component.
- In case of more width available, show more numbers instead of ellipsis (`...`).
- Show a dot (like a bullet) between the numbers. For this I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306108/css-styling-for-horizontal-list-with-bullet-only-between-elements/). But doesn't work well, it shows the dots below the numbers. Only works for the current number. See below:
  [image]

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbh9ft

Comment: do the displayed numbers, or rather the ellipse "change" if you set a fixed width to `.ngx-pagination`?

Comment: No, they don't. The `<ul>` element's width (the one with the `.ngx-pagination` class) changes, but the distance between the numbers is the same. And the ellipsis is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination/issues/313) in the package's Github repo and could achive what I wanted. I had to implement a custom template. For me was useful this [example](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination/tree/master/docs/src/components/custom-template-example).

I leave here the link to a demo in Stackblitz just in case someone finds it useful:

- Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxvecv