# Responsive Separator for Horizontal List - with a twist

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have looked into this question regarding horizontal lists: [Responsive Separator for Horizontal List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052659/responsive-separator-for-horizontal-list)

I am trying to achieve this but am running into some issues.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
var actionBox = document.getElementById('content');
switch (event.keyCode) {
  case 65:
    event.cancelBubble = true;
    event.returnValue = false;
    actionBox.innerHTML = '<ul id="content" class="name-container"> <li>Prename <strong>Name</strong></li> <li>Prename <strong>Name</strong></li> <li>Prename <strong>Name</strong></li> <li>Prename<strong>Name</strong></li></ul>';

    break;

}

return event.returnValue;
  }
```

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
li::after {
  content: " ";
  word-spacing: 1em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    -0.25turn,
    transparent 0 calc(50% - 0.03em),
    currentcolor 0 calc(50% + 0.03em),
    transparent 0
  );
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans Nova', sans-serif;
  background: no-repeat url('Hintergrund-01.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

#content {
  color: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
}

#name {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "gill-sans-nova", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#namestiftung {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "gill-sans-nova", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#vorname {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: gill-sans-nova, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;

}

#vornamestiftung {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: gill-sans-nova, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;

}

#titel {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: source-sans-pro, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

small {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: gill-sans-nova, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.smalltext {
  width: 100%;
}

#logo {
  margin-left: 4em;
  text-align: right;
}

#logo img {
  height: 10em;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  padding: 40px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.name-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  column-gap: 12px;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.name-container.four {
  font-size: 38px;
}

div.name-container div:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.name-container div:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(3n+1) {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="NOTG_2023_Logo.png" />
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <!-- ############### -->
      <!-- Content of Page -->
      <!-- ############### -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="names.js"></script>
  <script src="separator.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The content is placed by a javascript:

I used the css in the previously mentioned question.

Non the less there is no separator between the names although the ::after element is present

[image]

When using a predefined list, that above css works fine.

The solution should look like this:

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
li::after {
  content: " ";
  word-spacing: 1em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    -0.2turn,
    transparent 0 calc(50% - 0.03em),
    currentcolor 0 calc(50% + 0.03em),
    transparent 0
  );
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>foo</li>
 <li>bar</li>
 <li>baz</li>
 <li>gazonk</li>
 <li>qux</li>
 <li>quux</li>
</ul>
```

So this issue seems to be that the wrapping div#content is a flexbox. Why is this happening? I'd like to keep the flexbox :(

Comment: please post compiled/rendered HTML as your markup. The pseudo-elements are empty and as such have no width. Either use margins or better yet align them next to each other with the help of flexbox and then simply use `gap` to space them apart.

Answer (score 2):

Simply apply `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` to the `<ul>`. That will cause the list elements to be displayed next to each other and wrap like normal inline-elements. Then you can use `gap` to space the list elements apart:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Max <strong>Mustermann</strong></li>
  <li>John <strong>Doe</strong></li>
  <li>Tommy <strong>Tentpeg</strong></li>
</ul>
```